# Android not getting email id while login through facebook? only getting name and id

Tags: android, facebook, email

i am using Facebook sdk-4.5.0, trying to get the email id of user from facebook but i am not getting email id, also provide permission for email. can any one please help ?

here is the code...

```
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

    fbLoginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.authButton);
    fbLoginButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("public_profile", "email", "user_birthday"));
    fbLoginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            final Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
            displayMessage(profile);

            System.out.println("Facebook Login Successful!");
            System.out.println("Logged in user Details : ");
            System.out.println("--------------------------");
            System.out.println("User ID  : " + loginResult.getAccessToken().getUserId());
            System.out.println("Authentication Token : " + loginResult.getAccessToken().getToken());

            final AccessToken accessToken = loginResult.getAccessToken();
            //final FBUser fbUser = new FBUser();
            GraphRequest.newMeRequest(accessToken, new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(JSONObject user, GraphResponse graphResponse) {
                    if (graphResponse.getError() != null) {

                    } else {

                        ParseObject userObject = new ParseObject("UserDetail");
                        userObject.put("UserEmail", user.optString("email"));
                        userObject.put("UserName", user.optString("name"));
                        userObject.put("FacebookId", user.optString("id"));
                        userObject.saveInBackground();

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login Successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }).executeAsync();
```

Comment: i got the answer.. just get object of JSONObject from response
    JSONObject json = graphResponse.getJSONObject();

Answer (score 0):

```
FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());

// Private method to handle Facebook login and callback
private void onFaceBookLogin() {
    callbackmanager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    // Set permissions
    LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(this, Arrays.asList("public_profile, email, user_birthday, user_friends, user_location"));

    LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackmanager,
            new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(final LoginResult loginResult) {

                    // App code
                    GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                            loginResult.getAccessToken(),
                            new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                                @Override
                                public void onCompleted(
                                        JSONObject object,
                                        GraphResponse response) {
                                    // Application code

                                    try {
                                        Log.v("LoginActivity", response.toString());
                                        // Toast.makeText(Login_Activity.this,object.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                                        facebbok_id = object.getString("id");
                                        str_first_name = object.getString("first_name");
                                        str_last_name = object.getString("last_name");
                                        str_email = object.getString("email");

                                        /*str_gender = object.getString("gender");
                                        str_date_of_birth = object.getString("birthday");
                                        String tempdata = object.getJSONObject("location").getString("name");
                                        String tempdataArray[] = tempdata.split("\\s+");
                                        str_city = tempdataArray[0];
                                        str_country = tempdataArray[1];*/

                                        new LoginTask().execute();

                                    } catch (Exception e) {

                                    }


                                }
                            });
                    Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                    parameters.putString("fields", "id,first_name,last_name,email,gender,birthday,location");
                    request.setParameters(parameters);
                    request.executeAsync();

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancel() {
                    Log.d("On cancel", "On cancel");
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(FacebookException error) {
                    Log.d("On error", error.toString());
                }
            });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless your app has been approved to use that feature by facebook you will NOT be able to get that piece of information from your app.

The correct way around this would be to go to the Facebook Developers Console and make sure that your facebook account that you are testing with is listed as an Administrator or Developer. This will circumvent that need for Facebook to review your app for permissions for the users listed in those sections and will allow you to receive that data. This is meant for just testing purposes. In order to release your app with that Facebook permissions to be used by real users you will need to submit your app to Facebook for review.